# Modeling nested data using linear mixed modeling (specifically lme4)

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, repeated-measures, modeling, nested-data

I'll appreciate your help with conceptually understanding the models below.

I have data for 150 subjects who completed a cognitive task.
Each subject responded to four types of stimuli (A, B, C, D), and each type of stimulus was presented multiple times - see table below for an example data.

I'm interested in the effects of age, stimulus type (STIMTYPE) and their interaction, on time.

[image: Example data for 2 participants. Participants go thru 300 trials.]

Does this model make sense?

```
timer ~ age + stimtype + age:stimtype + (1|ID)
```

I think that it does not take into account the nested structure (multiple presentations for each stimulus type), correct? and if so - how do I model that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model:

```
timer ~ age + stimtype + age:stimtype + (1|ID)
```

will estimate the association of the fixed effects of `age`, `stimtype` and their interaction with `timer`, while adjusting for the repeated measures on participant (`ID`). You also have repeated measures of `stimtype` (and `age` for that matter), but since you are fitting fixed effects for these, this is also taken care of.

Comment: Thanks Robert, so I get from your answer that my model specification is plausible.